# How to get a token in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: api, sharepoint-2013, bearer-token

I'd like to use the restful api of sharepoint to access some documents but it seems impossible to get a proper/clear explanation on how to generate a token/bearer with a rest call (Jquery - PHP).

I just need a API endpoint and the right parameters please and if possible an example.